# make my code running continuously JS

Tags: javascript

could some one help to make my code running continuously in my page

Note : i'm using phprunner

```
    function funcAfter(fieldsData) {  
    for (f in fieldsData) {  
        var field = fieldsData[f];  
        if (field.name == 'Acceptance') {  
            if (field.value == 'Rejected') {  
                field.container.closest('td').css('background', 'red');  
                field.container.closest('td').css('color', 'white');  
            } else if (field.value == 'Accepted') {  
                field.container.closest('td').css('background', 'blue');  
                field.container.closest('td').css('color', 'white');  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}  
this.on('afterInlineEdit', funcAfter);  
this.on('afterInlineAdd', funcAfter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run that code continuously on your page you can use **setInterval** function, something like:

```
setInterval(funcAfter, 200) // 200 is the interval of time you want to run your code
```

But the above is a poor implementation, if you give more context the answer could be better

Comment: Thanks for replying, i don't know where can i put (set interval ) in my code